# In-app purchase: get the App Store from which a user made a purchase

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

Is it possible to tell if a purchase was made in the UK / US store for example?

Answer (score 1):

So far as I'm aware, I don't think there's a method of detecting the specific store which a user downloaded from, however the most reasonable solution would be to detect their locale, and assume that they're using the default store for their specific location.

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *country = [locale objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];

if ([country isEqualToString:@"UK"]){
    // United Kingdom
}
```

However, it's possible for a user to change their store settings on the device, so this solution may not work all the time.

Comment: I have a german device but a US AppStore account, I wouldn't be really happy if I would get something else than I bought just because my device is in german... So yeah, depending on what you want to do with the info, this really isn't the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you will do a `SKProductsRequest` and receive a list of products via get`SKProductsRequestDelegate`'s `- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest*)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse*)response`.

`response.products` is an array of `SKProduct`s.  And `SKProduct` has the `priceLocale`, which tells you from which country/App Store the purchase will be made.  That's it!